# How to use instance methods on sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

Can someone help me figure out how to use my `sequelize` instance methods on my controller?

I wrote my model like that:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Patient = sequelize.define('Patient', {
    email: { 
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password : { 
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      generateHash: function (password) {
                  return bcrypt.hash(password, 8, function(err, hash){
                      if(err){
                          console.log('error'+err)
                      }else{
                          return hash;
                      }
                  });
              },
      validPassword: function(password) {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
      }        
    }
  });
  return Patient;
};
```

but when I launch it on my controller which I made like that

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const passport = require('passport');
const Patient = require('../models').Patient;

module.exports = {
///
  create(req, res) {
    return Patient
      .create({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: Patient.prototype.generateHash(req.body.password)
      })
      .then(patient => res.status(201).send(patient))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```

I get this error for the request:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateHash' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `bcrypt.hashSync()` because you want to assign asynchronous function call to the `password` - it won't work.

```
generateHash: function(password){
    try {
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error: ' + e);
    }
}
```

In order to use instance method you should do

```
Patient.build().generateHash(req.body.password);
```

`build()` creates new instance of model so then you can run the instance method. Or you can declare the `generateHash` as a class method so you could run it like that

```
Patient.generateHash(req.body.password);
```